# How to make a rest call request from python using client certificate (in windows)

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, client-certificates

I'm trying to make a RESTfull call in Python (2.7) to a tomcat server and it must be done using SSL with client certificate.

The following line is how the call to tomcat is done:

```
result = requests.get(url, headers=headers, verify=settings.SLA_CA_SERVER_CERTIFICATE, cert=(settings.SLA_CLIENT_CERTIFICATE_PUBLIC, settings.SLA_CLIENT_CERTIFICATE_PRIVATE), **kwargs)
```

I got the following error:

[Errno 336265225] _ssl.c:355: error:140B0009:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file:PEM lib ()

I've tried using in the *cert*  variable *.pem* files and *.key* and *.crt* files and had no luck. The private key hasn't a password. Any clue why I'm having this error?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

I was creating the public certificate and private key from .p12 file using openssl in windows.
I created them using and openssl from linux (ubuntu) and it worked.

Just informative, the commands used to create the keys where

```
openssl pkcs12 -in path.p12 -out newfile.crt.pem -clcerts -nokeys    
openssl pkcs12 -in path.p12 -out newfile.key.pem -nocerts -nodes
```